# Is there a bulk.find.remove() in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Is https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.remove/ available in pymongo? See docs here - https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html. It looks like `bulk_write` exists in pymongo - https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/search.html?q=bulk - however I do not see anything for bulk.find.remove(). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The pymongo equivalent is DeleteMany. See https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/bulk.html?highlight=deletemany#ordered-bulk-write-operations

Simple example:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, DeleteMany

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
db.collection.insert_many({'a': x} for x in range(10))
result = db.collection.bulk_write([DeleteMany({'a': {'$gte': 5}})])
print(result.deleted_count)
```